# Rolling up multiple rows into a single row in exasol

Tags: sql, exasolution

I've ran the following query to find out the access rights assigned to each user :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       A.GRANTEE AS DB_ACCOUNT,
       B.PRIVILEGE AS ACCESS_RIGHTS
  FROM SYS.EXA_DBA_ROLE_PRIVS A
 INNER JOIN SYS.EXA_DBA_SYS_PRIVS B
    ON A.GRANTED_ROLE = B.GRANTEE;
```

The output of the query has each user having multiple access rights listed in row by row format, I need all **ACCESS_RIGHTS** listed into a single row for each user.

For Eg.: The output comes like this for all the users:

```
EXECUTE
SELECT
CREATE
```

whereas I need the output as :

`EXECUTE, SELECT, CREATE`

***I NEED A FUNCTION IN EXASOL***.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

use `group_concat` as

```
group_concat(B.PRIVILEGE) AS ACCESS_RIGHTS
```

this [***link***](https://www.exasol.com/support/browse/EXASOL-195) might be referenced for the format.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a function in Exasol for rolling up the rows into a single row and the function name is **GROUP_CONCAT**. Modified query is :

SELECT DISTINCT
A.GRANTEE AS DB_ACCOUNT,
**GROUP_CONCAT(B.PRIVILEGE) AS ACCESS_RIGHTS**
FROM 
SYS.EXA_DBA_ROLE_PRIVS A
INNER JOIN 
SYS.EXA_DBA_SYS_PRIVS B
ON
A.GRANTED_ROLE = B.GRANTEE
GROUP BY A.GRANTEE;